# Problem on partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have some confusion here.

The question is $u=x^n\:f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$ .

I need to find the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and shows that $x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=nu$.

The thing that I am confused is about $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ .

For $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, I have two different answers which are $x^n\left[f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\left(-\frac{x}{y^2}\right)\right]+f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\left(nx^{n-1}\right)$ and $x^n\left[f\left(\frac{x}{y^2}\right)\right]+f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\left(nx^{n-1}\right)$.

The same goes to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ .

Can someone explain to me how to get the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

Comment: Your question is unreadable, you need to surround your formulas with $ for better readability

Comment: done. i make mistakes and forgot to put the $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can work in a similar way to when we only have one variable: Let us start with $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and to make things more convenient let $g(x)=\frac{x}{y}$ and so $g'(x)= \frac{1}{y}$. We caclulate:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[x^{n}f(g(x))]\\
&= \frac{d x^{n}}{d x}\cdot f(g(x)) + x^{n} \cdot \frac{d f(g(x))}{dx}\\
&= nx^{n-1}f(g(x)) + x^{n}f'(g(x))g'(x)\\
&= nx^{n-1}f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) +  x^{n}f'\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\frac{1}{y}
\end{align*}
You can obtain $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ by working with the same principles of one variable differentiation. I recommend that you define $h(y)=\frac{x}{y}$ to see the similarity with the one variable case

Comment: so the $f\:'\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$ need to solve or not? Because it is f prime isn't it?

Comment: $f'(\frac{x}{y})\frac{1}{y}$ is the derivative of $f(\frac{x}{y})$ with respect to $x$, or as in my notation, the derivative of $f(g(x))$ with respect to $x$. There is no further differentiation needed.

Comment: okay I try to solve it as what you had explain to me. Thanks !

Comment: wait so if h(y)=x/y and the h'(y) = x isn't it? or $-\frac{x}{y^2}$ ?

Comment: The quotient rule applies, you treat $x$ like a constant, so $h'(y) = -\frac{x}{y^{2}}$ is correct